# ZF - MySQL SUM query using CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, prepared-statement

trying to write the following query in zend framework 1:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 'value1' THEN column3 END) AS 'mySpecialSum',
FROM `my_table` 
WHERE column4='value2' AND column5='value3'
```

to test I'm writing it like this:

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('my_table', array(
        'mySpecialSum'=>'SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = "value1" THEN column3 END)'
    ))
    ->where('column4=?', $value2)
    ->where('column5=?', $value3);
$data = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

which works - but i need to know how to include `value1` as a variable - eg `$value1` - preferably with placeholders so the statement is 'prepared' - to minimise the chance of SQL injection.

Currently trying two options (that are not working):

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('my_table', array(
        'mySpecialSum'=>'SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = "{$value1}" THEN column3 END)'
    ))
    ->where('column4=?', $value2)
    ->where('column5=?', $value3);
$data = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

OR

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('my_table', array(
        'mySpecialSum'=>'SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = "{$this->_db->quote($value1)}" THEN column3 END)'
    ))
    ->where('column4=?', $value2)
    ->where('column5=?', $value3);
$data = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html) on prepared statements, it appears the best method is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = ? THEN column3 END) AS "mySpecialSum",
FROM my_table
WHERE content_type = ?
AND content_id = ?';

$preparedStatement = $this->getAdapter()->query($sql, array($value1, $value2, $value3));
$data = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
```

Two options that are *also* working - but both feel like hacks (and are also, incidentally, slightly slower than the 'prepared statement' method above) - are:

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('my_table', array(
        'mySpecialSum'=>'SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = "' . $value1 . '" THEN column3 END)'
    ))
    ->where('column4=?', $value2)
    ->where('column5=?', $value3);
$data = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

and:

```
$start = microtime();

$select = $this->select()
    ->from('my_table', array(
        'mySpecialSum'=>'SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = ' . $this->_db->quote($value1) . ' THEN column3 END)'
    ))
    ->where('column4=?', $value2)
    ->where('column5=?', $value3);
$data = $this->fetchAll($select);

$end = microtime();
$timeTaken = $end - $start;
```

the `microtime()` before & after is a speed test to compare the two methods  :
...shows negligible difference for using zf `$this->_db->quote()` or not

However, strangely there's a 5 fold speed increase when using `$this->getAdapter()->select()` rather than simply using `$this->select()` :

```
$select = $this->getAdapter()
    ->select()
    ->from('my_table', array(
        'mySpecialSum'=>'SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = ' . $this->_db->quote($value1) . ' THEN column3 END)'
    ))
    ->where('column4=?', $value2)
    ->where('column5=?', $value3);
$data = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```